# Chebyshev inequality with the weak law of large numbers

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, law-of-large-numbers, variance

In order to estimate f. the true fraction of smokers in a large population. Someone selects n people at random. His estimator Mn is obtained by dividing Sn. The number of smokers in his sample by n, i.e., Mn = Sn/n. So, he chooses the sample size n to be the smallest number for which the Chebyshev inequality yields a guarantee that:

$$P(|M_n-f|\ge\varepsilon)\le\delta$$

Where epsilon and delta are some prespecified tolerances. Determine how the value of n recommended by the Chebyshev  inequality changes in the following cases.

a) The value of epsilon is reduced to half its original value.
b) The probability delta is reduced to half its original value.

Comment: The estimator $M_n$ has standard deviation $\frac{\sqrt{f(1-f)}}{\sqrt{n}}$. Now write down what the Chebyshev Inequality says. Can you pinpoint the source of your difficulty?

Comment: Hi, André. I don't know how to describe the relation between Mn and the Chebyshev inequality. Why the standard deviation is the one you just said? I guess you are treating Mn as a Bernoulli variable? But why f as probability?

Comment: The random variable $S_n$ has binomial distribution variance $f(1-f)n$. The random variable $M_n$ is obtained by dividing $S_n$ by $n$, so has variance $\frac{f(1-f)n}{n^2}$.

Comment: The Inequality says $\Pr(|M_n-f|\ge k\sigma)\le \frac{1}{k^2}$. Here $\sigma$ is the standard deviation mentioned in an earlier comment.

Comment: I understand now why it's binomial and why you told about that deviation but I don't get how I can use this information and combine it with delta, epsilon and the deviation information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in comments, the random variable $M_n$ has mean $f$ and standard deviation $\sigma_n=\frac{\sqrt{f(1-f)}}{\sqrt{n}}$.

The standard form of the Chebyshev Inequality (please see Wikipedia) says that
$$\Pr(|M_n-f|\ge k\sigma_n)\le \frac{1}{k^2}.\tag{1}$$
Suppose that we want to leave $\delta$ unchanged, but want to shrink $\epsilon$ by a factor of $2$. So in the notation of (1) we want to leave $\frac{1}{k^2}$ unchanged, meaning we want $k$ to be unchanged.

Since the original $\epsilon$ is $k\frac{\sqrt{f(1-f)}}{\sqrt{n}}$, to shrink it by a factor of $2$ while leaving $k$ unchanged, we need to multiply $\sqrt{n}$ by $2$, so  we need to multiply $n$ by $4$. Shrinking the width of the confidence interval is expensive!

Now it's your turn to find how $n$ should change if $\epsilon$ is unchanged, but $\delta$ changes to half its previous value.

Comment: Thank you, now I get it. For the second case we need to multiply n by 2 so we can keep epsilon with the same value and delta half of his original value.

Comment: That's right. Cutting the probability in the tail by a factor of $2$ is cheaper than cutting the size of the confidence interval by a factor of $2$.